# How to add a path to LDFLAGS

Tags: gnu, gmp, mingw32

I'm trying to set up a library called [PBC](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/) (Pairing-based cryptography). And this library requires another library called [GMP](http://gmplib.org/manual/) -(GNU Multiple-Precision Library).

My problem is after installing GMP correctly, PBC gives an error of:

> gmp library not found add its path to LDFLAGS

I have no idea what `LDFLAGS` is and how to add it to the path.

PS: I'm using MinGW.

Comment: Are you running "make" to compile PBC?  Did you look at the Makefile; that should have an LDFLAGS defined at the top.

Comment: @Foon, it has make i try with make but it gives this error though

Answer (score 15):

The question is not really descriptive enough for anyone to answer well, but....

On a Unix-based system you would likely do something like this:

```
$ export LDFLAGS="-R/the/path/to/the/gmp/lib -L/the/path/to/the/gmp/lib"
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

Windows environments with GNU make tools, will need minor tweaks.

Comment: What do R and L mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you look into [gcc man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html):

```
-Ldir
```

adds directory **dir** to the list of directories to be searched
for **-l**. So, **-Ldir** just passes a path to the linker to look for a **.a** or **.so** library used by the source code

**-Rdir** is [not always supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860024/what-does-the-gcc-r-parameter-do) by all platform,
a better option is [rpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562403/i-dont-understand-wl-rpath-wl) together with **-Wl**:

```
-Wl,-rpath=dir
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Just to make sure we can't make this easier: are you trying to compile something extra such that you can't (or don't want to; I have no problems if you prefer to compile everything from source or what not but want to make sure you just didn't see it) use the precompiled binaries someone already built using MinGW? ([Located here](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/files/pbc-0.5.12-win32-bin.zip) as of when I wrote this.)
2. `LDFLAGS` are a convention with a C compiler for flags that should be passed to the loader part. In your case, you're most likely going to want to add something like `-L/usr/local/lib` (or wheverer GMP got put... I would expect you can probably figure it out by searching for `libgmp.a` ... if necessary, in your msys shell, `cd` to `/` and run `find -name "libgmp.a"`).  If you open the `Makefile` in a text editor, you should find a `LDFLAGS` line, possibly empty (on my Linux box, it's just `LDFLAGS=` for that line).