# I don't understand -Wl,-rpath -Wl,

Tags: gcc, ld, rpath

For convenience I added the relevant manpages below.

My (mis)understanding first: If I need to separate options with `,`, that means that the second `-Wl` is not another option because it comes before `,` which means it is an argument to the `-rpath` option.

I don't understand how `-rpath` can have a `-Wl,.` argument!

What would make sense in my mind would be this:

```
-Wl,-rpath .
```

This should invoke `-rpath` linker option with the current directory argument.

---

man gcc:

> -Wl,option
>
> Pass option as an option to the
> linker. If option contains commas, it
> is split into multiple options at the
> commas. You can use this syntax to
> pass an argument to the option. For
> example, `-Wl,-Map,output.map` passes
> `-Map output.map` to the linker. When
> using the GNU linker, you can also get
> the same effect with
> `-Wl,-Map=output.map'.

man ld:

> -rpath=dir

> Add a directory to the
> runtime library search path. This is
> used when linking an ELF executable
> with shared objects. All -rpath
> arguments are concatenated and passed
> to the runtime linker, which uses them
> to locate shared objects at runtime.
> The -rpath option is also used when
> locating shared objects which are
> needed by shared objects explicitly
> included in the link;

Comment: Isn’t the title missing dot character at the end?

Comment: Yes, I suspect the SO software may have removed it

Answer (score 376, accepted):

The `-Wl,xxx` option for **gcc** passes a comma-separated list of tokens as a space-separated list of arguments to the **linker**. So

```
gcc -Wl,aaa,bbb,ccc
```

eventually becomes a linker call

```
ld aaa bbb ccc
```

In your case, you want to say "`ld -rpath .`", so you pass this to gcc as `-Wl,-rpath,.` Alternatively, you can specify repeat instances of `-Wl`:

```
gcc -Wl,aaa -Wl,bbb -Wl,ccc
```

Note that there is no comma between `aaa` and the second `-Wl`.

Or, in your case, `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,.`.

Comment: Oh I understand now, there is no discrimination between option or argument while passing stuff to the linker, it's just a string. So the second -Wl is redundant! Thanks :)

Comment: @Blub: It's not redundant! It's an alternative form, you *either* say `-Wl,-rpath,.` *or* you say `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,.`. Precisely one of the two, you cannot omit anything.

Comment: Has anyone had success in setting the rpath on OS X, i.e. with clang & ld64?

Comment: What would the syntax look like if you wanted to specify multiple rpaths? `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,. -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/my/lib`?

Comment: @Hintron: Yes, or `-Wl,-rpath,dir1,-rpath,dir2`, or `-Wl,-rpath=dir1,-rpath=dir2`.

Comment: Just in case anyone else wastes several minutes figuring this out - like I just did - the character after `-W` is a lowercase 'L', not the digit 'one'!  Doh!

Comment: So `gcc -Wl,-rpath,.` needs two commas as it adds *two* space-separated arguments to `ld`, as in `ld -rpath .`. Meanwhile `gcc -Wl,rpath=.` only needs one comma, as it adds *one* argument to `ld`, as in `ld -rpath=.`. See the comment from @Hintron after the answer from @Mike on support for the `-rpath=PATH` syntax.

Answer (score 76):

You could also write

```
-Wl,-rpath=.
```

To get rid of that pesky space.  It's arguably more readable than adding extra commas (it's exactly what gets passed to ld).

Comment: From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options under `-Wl,option`: "_When using the GNU linker_, you can also get the same effect with -Wl,-Map=output.map." To me, that seems to indicate that if you use a linker other than the GNU linker, the `=` syntax may not be supported.

Comment: You saved my day. Every other suggestion I saw said to use -rpath='$ORIGIN', but this never worked for me, whereas -rpath=. worked perfectly. +1 for you

Answer (score 45):

One other thing. You may need to specify the -L option *as well* - eg

```
-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/foo -L/path/to/foo -lbaz
```

or you may end up with an error like

```
ld: cannot find -lbaz
```

Answer (score 13):

The man page makes it pretty clear.  If you want to pass two arguments (`-rpath` and `.`) to the linker you can write

```
-Wl,-rpath,.
```

or alternatively

```
-Wl,-rpath -Wl,.
```

The arguments `-Wl,-rpath .` you suggested do NOT make sense to my   mind.  How is gcc supposed to know that your second argument (`.`) is supposed to be passed to the linker instead of being interpreted normally?  The only way it would be able to know that is if it had insider knowledge of *all* possible linker arguments so it knew that `-rpath` required an argument after it.

Comment: it is not unthinkable that the gcc analyses arguments and if something doesn't make sense, it automatically groups.

Comment: @Blub That (9-year-old) argument would make sense, if `.` _were_ a nonsensical argument to `gcc`. But it's not, there are all sorts of valid reasons you could be passing `.` as an argument to GCC itself. Which is why, unless it's introduced with a `-Wl,` redirection flag in front of it, the `.` (or any other argument) wouldn't be included as part of the linker command line, because in the absence of an explicit `-Wl,` or other subcommand redirection, naturally `gcc` will default to consuming every argument itself.

Answer (score 0):

i could solve this problem with this, change line and flag

LDFLAGS = -Wl,--export-dynamic

LIBDIR = -L *insert lib dir*

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. **It would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?