# how to remove path from the default gcc search path

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu, boost

When compiling with boost library in Ubuntu, how can I make sure the GCC use my boost path?

The current Boost version in Ubuntu is 1.46.

I compile version 1.52.

I know I can use "-L/path/to/new/lib" to add library to the search path,but how can I make sure GCC wont link to the old library?

Regards, Tomer

Answer (score 5):

The -L option adds library search paths to the beginning of the search path, so if you have your own version it will be found before the default system version.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the `-v` option to `gcc` or `g++` to understand what linking command it is running. You could even add `-Wl,--verbose` to have the `ld` command be also verbose.

You might also be interested in `-rpath`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6562437/841108).

Comment: How about the `--sysroot` option?

Comment: @H2CO3: doesn't `--sysroot` only apply when configuring GCC ??

Comment: I believe that's also an option when compiling/linking. IIRC it's the equivalent of `-isysroot` (which is included in Apple's fork of GCC).