# Am I writing this makefile correctly?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, makefile

I am learning how to write C code in Linux and I am learning makefiles at a very beginner level.
I am having problems when making shared libraries.

The exercise is to make a simple function calculator C program with files:

```
main.c
add.c
subt.c
mult.c
div.c
```

The names of the files define the function they do.
The function in the file subt.c is in the static library:

```
libsubstatic.a
```

The function in the file mult.c is in the shared library:

```
libmultshared.so
```

For this program, I write the following makefile:

```
calc.exe: main.o add.o div.o libsubstatic.a libmultshared.so
gcc -o calc.exe main.o add.o div.o libsubstatic.a -Wl,-rpath,/home/ahmed/Desktop/labTask3 -lmultshared.so

main.o: main.c header.h
gcc -c main.c

add.o: add.c header.h
gcc -c add.c

libsubstatic.a: subt.o
ar cr libsubstatic.a subt.o

subt.o: subt.c header.h
gcc -c subt.c

libmultshared.so: mult.o
gcc -shared -fPIC -o libmultshared.so mult.o

mult.o: mult.c header.h
gcc -c -fPIC mult.c

div.o: div.c header.h
gcc -c div.c
```

The path where the code and makefile is placed:

```
/home/ahmed/Desktop/labTask3
```

I get the following message after I type "make" in the terminal:

```
gcc -o calc.exe main.o add.o div.o libsubstatic.a -Wl, -rpath, /home/ahmed/Desktop/labTask3 -lmultshared.so
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-rpath,’
make: *** [calc.exe] Error 1
```

What am I missing? Did I write this makefile correctly?
Please explain shared libraries, my concept might be faulty.

Please help.

Note that, I'm new to linux and I don't have much experience in makefiles.

EDIT: I removed the spaces as directed in the first answer. Now the terminal says:

```
gcc -o calc.exe main.o add.o div.o libsubstatic.a -Wl,-rpath,/home/ahmed/Desktop/labTask3 -lmultshared.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmultshared.so
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [calc.exe] Error 1
```

Should I do something with the "-lmultshared.so"? What should I do?

Comment: See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20146082/841108) `Makefile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-Wl, -rpath, /home/ahmed/Desktop/labTask3
```

Get rid of the spaces. This should all be one long argument.

```
-Wl,-rpath,/home/ahmed/Desktop/labTask3
```

See [this excellent answer by @KerrekSB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6562437/68587) for a detailed explanation about passing arguments to the linker with `-Wl`.

Comment: I got rid of the spaces and it now says:
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmultshared.so
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [calc.exe] Error 1

Comment: @ahmedbatty Use `-L` to tell gcc where to find libraries if they're not in the standard locations (e.g., `/lib`, `/usr/lib`). You might try `-L.` to tell it to look in the current directory.