# Unable to load shared library : libxerces.so

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries

While running the application developed by other person, getting the following error

```
./appln: error while loading shared libraries: libxerces-c.so.28: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And if I run ldd command:

```
# ldd appln
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00e20000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00a61000)
libxerces-c.so.28 => not found
```

I already have that libxerces-c.so.28 file in current folder. Please help me how to resolve that error

Answer (score 3):

You need to put libxerces-c.so somewhere in the library path. Probably current folder is not searched for libraries. Try putting it in `/usr/local/lib`

Comment: Now I found that it is already there in /usr/local/lib, but still getting the error

Comment: or just do a `sudo make install` if you have build it (or `sudo ldconfig`)

Answer (score 2):

By default .so files are NOT being searched in the current folder (they should be in /usr/lib, etc).
To add the current directory for .so lookup use:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH  ./appln
```

Comment: $LD_LIBRARY is not there in my redhat linux

Answer (score 2):

Evidently "the current folder" isn't in the run time search path used by your executable. I'm  assuming that you are on linux (`linux-gate.so.1`).

You need to ensure that "the current" directory is under the search path. You can do this at link time by using the `-rpath` option to the linker (`-R` is also accepted) or `-Wl,-rpath,<dir>` if you are invoking the linker through the compiler front end. This embeds a search path to be used at run time into your program.

Consider how you want the program to be installed, though. There's no point in adding a path that is specific to your development environment. You might want to consider using `$ORIGIN` or a `$ORIGIN` relative path which tells the run time linker to look for shared objects in the location containing (or relative to) the executable. You should always avoid adding `.` to the run time search path; your program shouldn't behave differently depending on the current directory of the process which invokes it.

As a temporary measure you can set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to override the embedded and system search paths but it is normally a bad idea to rely on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` overrides for a final installation.

Comment: I am using redhat enterprise linux, what is the complete command that I need to execute

Comment: @RajeshKumar: I don't know what the copmlete command that you need to execute because I don't know how you link your executable now.

Answer (score 2):

When adding new "local system" libraries (e.g. in `/usr/local/lib/`) you better add that directory (`/usr/local/lib/`) once in your `/etc/ld.so.conf` and you should run `ldconfig` to update the linker cache (every time you add something inside `/usr/local/lib/`)

See [ldconfig(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html), [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)

If you want your own libraries, set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to a directory containing them (e.g. `$HOME/lib/` and to standard directories, e.g.

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

in your `~/.bashrc` (but I dislike that confusing practice, and prefer to manage my `/usr/local/lib/`).

You could also use some [`-Wl,-rpath` argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6562403/841108) but I really dislike that also.

Read also [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and [Drepper's paper: *How To Write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Comment: This answer I like best.