# Error loading shared libraries libclntsh.so.11.1 cannot open

Tags: c++, linux, oracle, cron

> Error while loading shared libraries: libclntsh.so.11.1 : cannot open
>   shared obj file no such file.  When running from crontab.

I complied my c++ program, its a proc program after compiling proc I will run the below command.

```
g++ filename.CPP -I $ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public -L $ORACLE_HOME/lib -lclntsh -o test
```

I created a crontab to run it every min

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * /home/test > /home/te.txt 2>&1
```

I made a symbolic link of that library. But I'm getting above error inside te.txt

Im searching this for past 2 days and also went through the similar question, but still I not able to clear the error.

I'm not sure with `LD_Library_path` or `.bash_profile`. how to include that library.

Comment: The command `/home/test > /home/te.txt 2>&1` does not make sense. You should instead have something like `/bin/sh /path/to/script` and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Your can export library path in your .bash_profile like

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
```

or you can copy your libclntsh.so in /usr/lib/ or /lib

Comment: I will try this . Could I able to do this without root user privilege.

Comment: exporting path doesn't require root user privilege but if you need to copy lib to /usr/lib/ or /lib then root user privilege required

Comment: My .bash_profile contains export LD_LIBRARY_PATH, poiting correctly to $oracle_home/lib. Even now I'm getting the same error..

Comment: I think crontab executing your binary using root so you need to add this to root user's .bash_profile or you need to run cron using other user which .bash_profile have exported path

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux (using GNU Binutils) you can also compile-in the library path directly into the binary. [See -Wl,-rpath=...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562403/i-dont-understand-wl-rpath-wl)

But anyway (unless you use Oracle instant client lib) you should also export ORACLE_HOME env. var in crontab. Otherwise your application will not by able to localize .nls nor .ora (tnsnames.ora) files.