# loading a shared library from any directory

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, loader

I'm playing with shared library linking and loading procedures, and trying to learn about different ways to tackle the loading error:

`error while loading shared libraries: ... : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I managed to solve it by using LD_LIBRARY_PATH and by using rpath. I now try to comprehend the usage of ldconfig and how it can solve it, too [some of my web sources: [1](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html#fnref:2), [2](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html), [3](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) ]

So, I've got the following source files: `test.c func1.c func2.c`. Here's what I do:

1. Compiling them into PIC .obj files:

`$ gcc -Wall -fPIC -c *.c`

2. Creating a shared library from the object files, naming it 'libshared.so', and using 'soname':

`$ gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libshared.so -o libshared.so *.o`

3. Linking with a shared library by telling GCC where to find the shared library (the `...` is just an abbreviation for my personal shared library path):

`$ gcc -L/home/.../my_shared_library -Wall -o mytest test.c -lshared`

4. Now, I try running it, and get the loading error:

`./mytest: error while loading shared libraries: libshared.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

5. So I try telling the loader to search my private directory for the shared library file:

`ldconfig -n home/.../my_shared_library`

(I also tried it with: `ldconfig -n .-L` when my working directory is home/.../my_shared_library)

and tried running it once again, but I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use [GNU Libtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/) to simplify the process and avoid such errors.
Also use `-fPIC` option when you build your library.

Comment: Thanks for this tool, I wasn't familiar with it. However, I want to use 'direct' shell commanding, ldconfig specifically, and not hide the complexity of using shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO) & Drepper's paper: [*How to Write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

You probably want to set the [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6562403/841108).

You might load your plugin at runtime with [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html). Notice that shared object paths without any `/` are handled specially.

Comment: the HowTo manual is one of my learning sources, and I linked to a specific page that discusses my question content. I'm familiar with rpath, as I wrote, but I want to make things work using ldconfig (How to Write Shared Libraries also doesn't help regarding this).

Comment: But you don't set `rpath`.  I would put  once `/usr/local/lib/` in `/etc/ld.so.conf`, put the library under `/usr/local/lib/` and run `ldconfig`

Comment: Well, my understanding is that `ldconfig -n <my personal directory>` should make it possible for the loader to search the specified directory after my shared library, without the need to put it into /usr/local/lib, and without the need to use rpath. This understanding stems from some reading, and here's one example: "You can use gcc's -L flag in simple cases. You can use the ``rpath'...'" (from here [link] http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)