# Linker cannot find existing library

Tags: c++, mysql

I try to create a program for my raspberry using the Crosscompiler Tools from [SysGCC](http://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/). And I'm using MySQL CPPConn for this program. But after i've added mysqlclient and mysqlcppconn libraries i get weird errors:

```
d:/program data/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: warning: libz.so.1, needed by D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmysqlclient.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
d:/program data/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: warning: libdl.so.2, needed by D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmysqlclient.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

My eclipse uses the following command for compiling:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf" -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\local\lib" -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib" -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf" -lpthread -o "SensorBox"  ./DBController.o ./DS18B20.o ./main.o   -llog4cpp -lnsl -lmysqlclient -lmysqlcppconn
```

after trying the commands:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf" -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\local\lib" -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib" -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf" -lpthread -rpath "D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1" -o "SensorBox"  ./DBController.o ./DS18B20.o ./main.o   -llog4cpp -lnsl -lmysqlclient -lmysqlcppconn
```

and

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf" -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\local\lib" -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib" -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf" -lpthread -rpath-link "D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1" -o "SensorBox"  ./DBController.o ./DS18B20.o ./main.o   -llog4cpp -lnsl -lmysqlclient -lmysqlcppconn
```

I got the error messages:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-rpath'
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-rpath-link'
```

The files libz.so.1 and libdl.so.2 are existing in:

```
D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

After the comment from Mathieu Van Nevel, I tried also:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf" -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\local\lib" -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib" -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf" -lpthread -Wl,-rpath,"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1" -o "SensorBox"  ./DBController.o ./DS18B20.o ./main.o   -llog4cpp -lnsl -lmysqlclient -lmysqlcppconn
```

But it leads to the same errors as without "-rpath":

```
d:/program data/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: warning: libz.so.1, needed by D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmysqlclient.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
d:/program data/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: warning: libdl.so.2, needed by D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmysqlclient.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

Any Idea why the linker can't find these files?

Thanks

integer

Comment: not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link) : have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. And it gave me an errormessage like: "error: unrecognized command line option '-rpath'"

Comment: Please edit you question with the other command line you used then.

Comment: May be useful : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562403/i-dont-understand-wl-rpath-wl)

Comment: I've edited my questions with the results from your link

Comment: rpath need a directory. Try to make a small example, only a main with libmysqlclient linked (i can't test anything myself sorry).

Comment: I'm an Idiot! As I tried rpath without Wl, i tried the directory and then with the file directly. And as I tried -Wl,-rpath... I made a Copy-Paste-error. Now it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562403/i-dont-understand-wl-rpath-wl) using Wl and rpath worked for me:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf" -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\local\lib" -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\lib" -L"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf" -lpthread -Wl,-rpath-link,"D:\Program Data\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\lib\arm-linux-gnueabihf" ...
```