# What is the purpose of -Wl in the gcc/g++ command?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, g++

I Google it, but find no suitable documents that make me clear about `-Wl`.

Example:

```
gcc -Wl,--start-group foo.o bar.o -Wl,--end-group
```

Comment: You need to improve your google fu. From the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options): "-Wl,option Pass option as an option to the linker"

Comment: Google takes "-" to mean exclusion, Searching "-Wl" will exclude all results containing Wl ;)

Comment: @trevor Clearly we need a set of man pages that contain every term except the flag they are covering.

Comment: @yakk The GCC man page is about the most unusable man page there is. Waaay to long.

Comment: @kaylum Many thanks, but even reading gcc manual, I still cannot figout the purpose of -Wl. Stupid me...Hope to get more detailed explanation.

Comment: answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6562437/4490542

Comment: Can someone provide the commands that actually get passed to gcc and ld from original poster question please ?