# C++ program not linking to .so file properly

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries, glew

I built GLEW (using `make install`) to use in a small test program I am writing (source can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/WickedJet/1d931dfce90f7f33d3fd7db0f1e9e70d) if you need it). I ran `locate libGLEW.so` just to check if the GLEW libraries were properly installed, and got the following output:

```
/usr/lib64/libGLEW.so
/usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.2.0
/usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.2.0.0
```

This was completely normal. I then compiled it using the command:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -lglfw -lGLEW -lGL -lX11 -lpthread -lXi -g
```

This also threw up no errors. However, when I tried to execute the program:

```
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libGLEW.so.2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Just for a sanity check, I ran `ldd main | grep "GLEW"`, and sure enough:

```
libGLEW.so.2.0 => not found
```

I initially thought that this could be a problem with the linker not searching the directory containing the libraries. So I ran the command `ld --verbose | grep "/usr/lib64"` and there *was* a SEARCH_DIR containing the required directory:

```
...  SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64"); ...
```

This was especially confusing. I tried compiling with the `-L/usr/lib64` option, but the same error message still persisted. I checked that the symlinks to the library were correct and they were:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   16 Jul 15 10:22 libGLEW.so -> libGLEW.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   16 Jul 15 10:38 libGLEW.so.2.0 -> libGLEW.so.2.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 707K Jul 15 10:22 libGLEW.so.2.0.0
```

I am not sure what exactly is causing the issue but I'm starting to believe that I didn't install the libraries correctly. I feel like the answer is right in front of my eyes but I can't find it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What does 'uname -a' show?

Comment: @JohnHinrichsen Linux TRASHTOPB 4.8.0-58-generic #63~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 18:08:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Compile with `-Wl,-rpath=/usr/lib64`

Comment: According to g++ neither of these are valid command line options.

Comment: That is a single flag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562403/i-dont-understand-wl-rpath-wl

Answer (score 1):

Debian and Ubuntu do not install system libraries into `/usr/lib64`, and the installation instructions you used are wrong for those systems.  (It is not a good idea to install libraries bypassing the packaging system into `/usr` anyway.)  `/usr/local/lib` is searched by default (unlike other systems), so you could move the libraries to that directory.

Comment: I gave that a try, however the program is still not linked properly to libGLEW.so.2.0. I may try this on a different system to check if it's a problem with my computer.

Comment: Same as before, when I run`ldd main` it isn't linked properly to libGLEW.so.2.0