# What does the gcc -R parameter do?

Tags: c++, g++, autotools

I am trying to run an autotools configure script for the bson-cpp project, and it fails because it cannot determine what flags it needs to compile with boost_filesystem. A quick look at confg.log shows:

```
g++ -o conftest -g -O2   -pthread  -L/usr/local/lib -R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/libexec conftest.o -lboost_filesystem-mt  -lboost_system-mt >&5
g++: error: unrecognized option '-R'
```

So, naturally, I tried to find out what the R option does, but I can't seem to find it documented anywhere. I've checked [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary) and [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) to no avail. What does the option do and how do I tell autotools not to use it?

Comment: It's not necessarily a problem, `configure` tries different methods to find out what works on the actual platform. Option `-R dir` is gone now, it has been replaced with simpler (albeit platform-specific) options, like `-Wl,-rpath,dir`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

-R does not seem to be an option for g++ or gcc anywhere.  -R may be a linker option on some platforms that is equivalent of -rpath to gnu ld, ... This seems to be a known bug in boost builds ... have a look at [Use -Wl to pass arguments to the linker.](https://github.com/tsuna/boost.m4/commit/7d76670ecc1ae293cedb5ac0329db30c4059bf75)

It actually has the patch available there

**I am re-posting it for convenience, however PLEASE PLEASE look at the original URL linked above for official patch!**

```
--- ../gnote/m4/boost.m4    2011-01-25 14:30:18.000000000 +0200
+++ m4/boost.m4 2011-02-27 20:57:11.686221539 +0200
@@ -403,7 +403,7 @@
       LDFLAGS=$boost_save_LDFLAGS
       LIBS=$boost_save_LIBS
       if test x"$Boost_lib" = xyes; then
-        Boost_lib_LDFLAGS="-L$boost_ldpath -R$boost_ldpath"
+        Boost_lib_LDFLAGS="-L$boost_ldpath -Wl,-R$boost_ldpath"
         Boost_lib_LDPATH="$boost_ldpath"
         break 6
       else
```

Comment: man, thanks a lot, you saved me quite some trouble. It compiles now just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

It's an option similar to `-rpath`, but available only on some platforms. The script is maybe failing detecting your platform ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a valid option for GCC, so it does not do anything.

It is possibly a valid option for other compilers though, which could be why `autoconf` gives it a shot.

Not all errors in the `config.log` files are a problem. `autoconf` figures out a lot of things by "guessing", i.e. trying something and keeping that if it worked.

Comment: see my edit, but valid option or not, do you know how I can disable it?

Comment: your edit doesn't mean it's a valid option. (Try with all the other capital letters.) My point is: that error in config.log is _probably_ not a problem. A config.log from a successful configure run is always full of errors.

Comment: oh whoops, you are correct, made an assumption there haha (it doesn't work if I do -R/usr for example).

Comment: BTW, `-R` is an option for `ld`. Some versions of GCC might pass it on directly to the linker on some implementations.