# GCC Compiler - unrecognized option '-R/usr'

Tags: gcc, centos, configure

I am attempting to install Cosign on CentOS 6.3 64-bit to work with my employer's central login system.

Their documentation states that I need to set an LDFLAGS directive of:

```
    LDFLAGS="-R/usr -L/usr"
```

Where /usr is the /PATH/TO/SSL/lib - openSSL is installed and this is the correct path.

However when I then try to ./configure the installation, GCC is throwing an error which I can't work out.

```
    configure:2335: checking for suffix of executables
    configure:2342: gcc -o conftest -pthread  -R/usr -L/usr conftest.c  >&5
    gcc: unrecognized option '-R/usr'
```

I can't find -R as an option in the gcc docs, which has me confused. I'm using gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4).

I am not used to seeing options without a space before their argument, but in this case adding a space to make it '-R /usr' just throws the same error.

Earlier in the config.log, I also have this error:

```
    configure:2182: gcc -V >&5
    gcc: '-V' option must have argument
```

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the gcc -R parameter do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860024/what-does-the-gcc-r-parameter-do)

Comment: Thanks, although the downvote is a little unfair. Stack overflow treats any minus symbol as an 'omit from search' operator by default. So a typical search of gcc -r wouldn't bring anything up, either in the main search or in the suggested questions area when submitting a question. With this in mind, it's not unreasonable that I couldn't determine that this question might be a duplicate.

Comment: I did not down-vote you, as I was looking for an answer I stumbled upon the similar question which I reported back. Personally I think you question is reasonable and contains a nice amount of details, so I do not see the reason behind the down-vote. If I were you I won't care too much about one down-vote..! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDFLAGS should not be fed to gcc "as is", strange as they are like in your output. Probably some bug in the build script.

Try

```
 LDFLAGS="-Wl,-R/usr,-L/usr"
```

This should compensate the current error by wrapping the flags in the form that gcc expects.

Comment: No clue. -V specifies which version of the GCC should run hence must be followed by the version number, and it is not. Your configure seems seriously broken.